# All the websites detect wrong OS and browser version of my computer. Why?

Tags: firefox, browser, user-agent

I am using Windows 10 (insider build) and Firefox 58.0.2. But all the browser detection sites like www.whatismybrowser.com and similar says that I am using Firefox 52 on Windows 7. Detection scripts also return wrong screen resolution.

Can anyone say why is that? Maybe some firefox plugin - but I am not using any that would do that, that I know of. Maybe uBlock Origin?

Comment: Can you provide any relevant data, for example, what plugins you have installed (and their versions)

Comment: Can you post this to [su] instead because this doesn't have anything to do with programming.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the setting `privacy.resistFingerprinting` turned on in about:config, Firefox will pretend to be the most recent ESR version (in this case 52) on the most common OS (Windows 7).

This is to make your browser's user agent string the same as a lot of other people's, so it's harder for sites to use it to identify you.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1418672